# How to save colored text with bash color in txt file?

Tags: php, bash, fwrite

i don't know how to make this code correctly.

I have a code like this:

```html
$hasil = "\e[1;42mGreen Text";
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $hasil . "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

I want colored text to be stored in data.txt .

If like this, it does not become colored text, but the code is saved into text.

Comment: what output do you want to store in text file?

Comment: Well, you can't. Text files don't contain any formatting information. If you want color, use a different format (.doc, .odf, html....)

Comment: ok , if the format is html, so what the code i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$hasil = "<a style='color:green'>Text</a>";
$fp = fopen('data.html', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $hasil . "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

**After saving data in html file open it in your browser**

or check another example

```
$output = convertBash('[1;42m Text');
echo $output;
//
// Converts Bashoutput to colored HTML
//
function convertBash($code) {
    $dictionary = array(
        '[1;30m' => '<span style="color:black">',
        '[1;31m' => '<span style="color:red">', 
        '[1;42m' => '<span style="color:green">',   
        '[1;33m' => '<span style="color:yellow">',
        '[1;34m' => '<span style="color:blue">',
        '[1;35m' => '<span style="color:purple">',
        '[1;36m' => '<span style="color:cyan">',
        '[1;37m' => '<span style="color:white">',
        '[m'   => '</span>'
    );
    $htmlString = str_replace(array_keys($dictionary), $dictionary, $code);
    return $htmlString;
}
```

Comment: Whether it can not use bash color ? because it is only a example of my code.